# Django Ajax "FORBIDDEN" error

Tags: python, ajax, django, json

I've seen instances where people are getting forbidden errors while attempting to make remote Ajax requests, but I'm making a local request and I also have CSRF turned on in my middleware.

errorThrown is returning "Forbidden"

I think the issue might be that I'm trying to send this to a normal view (the current page)...  I'm not sure if my preprocessor is returning to the view to re-render the page.. or if it's returning right back to my current page.  (don't think I explained that very well)

Hopefully this gives you a good enough picture of whats going on.  Any/All help is appreciated.

the .ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(json) {
              jQuery(".signup").attr('disabled', false);
              $('.success').show();
              console.log(json.message);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              jQuery(".signup").attr('disabled', false);
              $('.fail').show().append(errorThrown);
              console.log(textStatus);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Wow, this question really helped me out. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need a CSRF token even if the request is to the same domain. There's code here to add a CSRF token to your AJAX requests (with jQuery):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

This link points to version 1.7, if you are using a different version of Django you can select your version from the floater menu on the bottom right.

Comment: Is that specifically for AJAX?  I have the CSRF middleware added already.

Comment: Ahh nevermind.. I see now.  I have another JSON error but that's irrelevant.  Thanks.

Comment: Worth noting that link points to version 1.3, and the code has been changed slightly since.

Comment: I had the same problem (403 errors with ajax calls), following the method described in the docs linked above was painless and fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

You will get 403 errors if you have csrf on, try adding in `views.py` to see if this is causing it:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
view class/method
```

Comment: I must respectfully disagree with this answer. It would be far better to add the CSRF token to the request than it is to exempt the view from CSRF altogether.

Comment: @Luke I second that! Certainly, add CSRF protection back in place once you know that this was the issue.

Comment: Except this decotator exists for a reason : on AJAX application with numérous calls, it can be preferable to exemple the view from protection at the begining of the projet, otherwise, you would have nothing to show you client for the deadline.

Comment: This answer is very valuable. You might have added some "blah blah" about thinking twice before exempting the view from CSRF, but generally there is nothing to "disagree" in this answer. And it is better by far than turning off CSRF middleware, and decorating views with CSRF protection "where needed". In a browser you can indulge yourself in cookies etc., but when writing a simple Webservice which should be accessible with e.g. `urllib2` without too much hacking - there's nothing bad about `@csrf_exempt`!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you still want CSRF protection, read my solution.

In my case I have a template in which I don't want to have a `<form></form>` element. But I still want to make AJAX POST requests using jQuery.

I got 403 errors, due to CSRF cookie being null, even if I followed the django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/). The solution is in the same page, mentioning the `ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator.

My CSRF cookie did get set when I added this at the top of my `views.py`:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
@ensure_csrf_cookie
```

Also, please note that in this case you *do not need* the DOM element in your markup / template: `{% csrf_token %}`

Comment: What if you're not in a browser and want to POST on your first request? (not necessarily as "AJAX", but say REST)

Answer (score 1):

Download jQuery.Cookie and include it, from here: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Then, add `beforeSend` function and send csrf token like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataString,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
    },
    success: function(json) {
          jQuery(".signup").attr('disabled', false);
          $('.success').show();
          console.log(json.message);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          jQuery(".signup").attr('disabled', false);
          $('.fail').show().append(errorThrown);
          console.log(textStatus);
    }

});
```

Comment: This was asked 5 years ago

Comment: I had same problem, then I want to post my solution. I think maybe someone can benefit.